# How can I test a live product with Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I just recently added a new product in my Stripe account and I wonder how I can test it. I tried to get the product checkout code and replace the live API key with the test key but it doesn't work. I searched all the Stripe documents and can't find anything about testing a product. I see a lot about Stripe plugin but if you just turn on the test mode and you can test the product easily but I can't do it in a native way. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace your stripe api key in your code by the test api key from your Stripe account.

Look at this tutorial : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe--pre-80957

Comment: Yes as I said I replaced the live key with the test key but it still not work.

Comment: What happen when you try to order something?

Comment: I still see it as a live paygate and I can't use the test card  number.